# css 3d animation issue in chrome

Tags: html, css, animation, 3d

i am experimenting with some 3d animations.

here is **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jedac/1)**

in demo the two slides are rotating on top of each other.

the problem is they are not behaving like real world 3d object.
please take a look at demo link above.

here is my code. its pretty state forward.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="one"></div>
        <div class="two"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .main {
            position: relative;
            margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            -moz-perspective: 1200px;
            -ms-perspective: 1200px;
            -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
            perspective: 1200px;
            -moz-perspective-origin: center left;
            -ms-perspective-origin: center left;
            -webkit-perspective-origin: center left;
            perspective-origin: center left;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
        }

        .one, .two {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .one {
            background-color: #0094ff;
            -moz-animation: spin 5s infinite both linear;
            -o-animation: spin 5s infinite both linear;
            -webkit-animation: spin 5s infinite both linear;
            animation: spin 5s infinite both linear;
        }

        .two {
            background-color: #ba3c3c;
            -moz-animation: spin2 5s infinite both linear;
            -o-animation: spin2 5s infinite both linear;
            -webkit-animation: spin2 5s infinite both linear;
            animation: spin2 5s infinite both linear;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes spin {
            from {
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
            }

            to {
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
            }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes spin {
            from {
                -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
            }

            to {
                -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
            }
        }

        @keyframes spin {
            from {
                transform: rotateY(0);
            }

            to {
                transform: rotateY(360deg);
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes spin2 {
            from {
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
            }

            to {
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(460deg);
            }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes spin2 {
            from {
                -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
            }

            to {
                -moz-transform: rotateY(460deg);
            }
        }
        @keyframes spin2 {
            from {
                transform: rotateY(90deg);
            }

            to {
                transform: rotateY(460deg);
            }
        }
```

**My questing is why they are flickering while animating?  am i doing anything wrong? or is it a browser issue?**

i can't figure out, please help.

Comment: You need four elements, not two. When the space is rotated 45 degrees, you want the right side of `.one` to be stacked over the right side of `.two` so it's visible, yet at the same time you want its left side to be stacked under `.two` so that it is hidden from view. That isn't possible. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ChrisHardie thanks i will try using four elements

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in chrome and firefox.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116710

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=689498

Safari is the only browser that can handle it.